# How can I set up a second Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter

I wanted to start a separate Twitter feed on a specific topic (with a different user name) that is separate from the primary one I use. When I tried to create the second account it wouldn't let me because it said my e-mail account was already in use (by my primary account, of course).

Is there a way to have two Twitter feeds that doesn't force me to set up another e-mail account somewhere just to use for Twitter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you happen to use GMail, you can fool the system.  On GMail's end, they ignore "." and anything after a "+" in the username.

All of the following are equivalent in GMail's eyes and would end up in the same inbox:

- rchern
- r.chern
- r.c.h.e.r.n
- rchern+twit1
- rchern+twit2

Comment: That worked great. My e-mail address at gmail was firstname.lastname@gmail.com and I confirmed that firstnamelastname@gmail.com does go to the same inbox. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

If you use gmail, you can register using username+[anything]@gmail.com (replace [anything] with whatever you want) and it will count as a different address.

I don't think it's possible without using another email address and yes it is stupid.